# Can't update database with Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am using UpdateView of Django (1.5.8) to update an object in my database. I edit the question object and hit submit; it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't update the question either.

I have my QuestionUpdate class in views.py which extends to UpdateView:

```
class QuestionUpdate(UpdateView):  
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    success_url = '.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

I call QuestionUpdate in urls.py with this:

```
url(r'^question/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='question_update', ),
```

In the template, I use Bootstrap form-group. I display a text area with a default value which is the original question.
Here is my template (I copy only the related part-the form):

```
        <form action = "" method ="post"> {% csrf_token %}

        <div class='form-group'>
                <label>Question</label>
                <textarea class='form-control' rows="3">{{question}}</textarea>
            </div>

            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' />

        </form>
```

I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/), but it doesn't help me so much. What am i missing?

There are two things I suspect:

1. I pass the pk to the url when I display the questions with updateview. I saw couple UpdateView examples using *reverse()* on the url. I don't know if I need it or why I need it. That might be the problem?
2. In my form, I display only the question_text, but there are other fields in the Question model. Am I having trouble because of the '*hidden fields*'?

EDIT: 
Here are the Question model and QuestionForm model form:

*models.py:*

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField()
    question_type = models.CharField(choices = Option_type, max_length = 64)
    calculate = models.CharField(choices=Calculation, blank = True, max_length = 64)
    ordering = models.IntegerField()
    scale_id = models.IntegerField()
    scale = models.ForeignKey(Scale)
    max_score_of_question = models.IntegerField()
    showQues = models.IntegerField(default = 1)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

*forms.py*

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
#         fields = ('question_text',)
```

Comment: Why do you think your form is valid? Override the method `form_invalid` to see what errors are you getting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've overriden the form_invalid but form is valid. It doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that I've changed my template to  {{ form.as_p }} and displayed all the fields. In the old version, form was invalid. Thanks for pointing out. And in this new version (with all fields), I am getting a Database Error : multiple assignments to same column.

Comment: Add your `QuestionForm` so that we can see it.

Comment: I added both the model and the modelform

Comment: I think the problem is that you've columns `scale_id` and `scale`. See - if there's a `ForeignKey`, it generates also a property named as the column + a suffix `_id`, in this case `scale_id` which collides with the column `scale_id` which is already there.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thank you a million times. Foreign key was the problem. When I removed the foreign key relation from Question model, it worked just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've columns `scale_id` and `scale`. See - if there's a `ForeignKey`, it generates also a property named as the column + a suffix `_id`, in this case `scale_id` collides with the column `scale_id` which is already there.

Just rename or remove one of them.